# What's the difference between LibGDX Sound and Music types?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

What is difference between Sound and Music types in LibGDX? This worked both on desktop and Android:

```
Music gameMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("sound/gamemusic.mp3"));
gameMusic.play();:

Sound gameMusic = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sound/gamemusic.mp3"));
gameMusic.play();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Music is streamed, while Sound is loaded into memory.
(Because Android with libgdx has limit of 1mb file for 'sound', Music can be of greater size)

It is said so here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Sound-effects

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Streaming-music

And according to another question on SO, you must wait a frame before you can play a Sound directly after loading:
[No Sound in Android Application with Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905364/no-sound-in-android-application-with-libgdx?rq=1)

Comment: and what can cause this error?WAV files must have 16 bits per sample: 8

Comment: Well, it says that the WAV file must be sampled with 16-bit and not 8-bit, so you'd have to convert the WAV to 16-bit, or convert (and compress) it to another format like OGG.

Comment: so what is the difference between 16 and 8 bit wav file?

Comment: The sound is sampled into 8-bits or 16-bits. This influences quality but also filesize, as you can store more sounds in 16 bits than you can in 8 bits; but obviously it needs twice as much space. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth