# Libgdx not playing sound android

Tags: android, audio, libgdx

Can't play sound on libgdx android.

```
Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sound.wav"));
sound.play();
```

I've placed "sound.wav" to assets folder.

Comment: Maybe this answer help you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905364/no-sound-in-android-application-with-libgdx

Comment: didn't help this solution

Comment: Did you try bumping up all of the different types of volumes?

Comment: Take a look at your volume mixer. Your game's volume might be turned off. Also, where are putting this code? You might be doing it wrong. It could also be a bug, maybe restart your computer.

Comment: @TobLoef ye, i solved it. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was, that when i call Sound `sound=Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sound.wav"));`

it takes a while to load the sound, so I decided to load all sounds in my create() method and call `sound.play()` when needed and it worked. Sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: Accept your answer ;)